# Nginx Denied All files/nested files and forward all request to index.php

Tags: nginx

The goal is to block every file/nested file as well as root files and forward all traffic to index.php except those files reside inside the static directory or nested static directory.

Here is config so far it's redirecting all traffic but issue with blocking others.

```
listen               80 default_server;

root                 "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test";

access_log           /Applications/MAMP/logs/nginx_access.log;
error_log            /Applications/MAMP/logs/nginx_error.log;

# block hidden files
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

# forward all traffic to index.php      
location / {
     index index.php;
     try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}


# block everthing else       
# location ~* ^\/.+$ { block all; }

# only allow files inside static directory (even from nested static)        
location ~* ^.*\/static\/.*$ {
    allow all;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to redirect request to `index.php` if requested file from `static` directory not found? Or just return 404 HTTP error?

Comment: yes redirect to index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
location / {
    rewrite . /index.php last;
}

location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
}

location ~* /static/ {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this- getting an empty response on root . Blank page nothing showing.

Comment: How are you process PHP scripts? PHP-FPM or apache backend? Anyway try replacing `break` flag of `rewrite` directive to `last` (edited my answer).

Comment: it seems likely working but another problem comes in now /some?foo=bar showing 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: query params throwing 500 Internal Server Error (followed your answer and break doesn't seem working)

Comment: Can you try simply `rewrite . /index.php last;`?

Comment: It seems that now it's working? You don't need an `index` directive in the first location block too.

Comment: cool, it's working as expected. thank you so much, you saved my day. I lost my hair scratching this issue. can you modify your answer as I used?

Comment: can you tell me if I only want to allow root's "/static" directory, how to do it?

Comment: Use ["start-of string" anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for URI check: `location ~* ^/static/ { ... }`